# Dictionary Key Value Missing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I tried to copy an array from a plist file but I lost the key value of this array. This is how I load the contents of plist:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Cars" ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.brand = [dict objectForKey:@"Chevrolet"];
```

The new dictionary **brand** contains ONLY **Chevrolet** cars (It is an array of strings). The new dictionary is declared as:

```
NSDictionary *brand;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *brand;
```

I would like to maintain the key value **Chevrolet** but I only have its content (The strings array). Is the only way, loop and build the new dictionary content with???:

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Camaro", @"Corvette", nil];
NSDictionary *brand =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objects forKey:@"Chevrolet"];
```

MORE INFORMATION:

DECLARATION OF NSDictionary **brand** (IN THE HEADER FILE):

```
NSDictionary *brand;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *brand;
```

CONTENT OF PLIST:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Chevrolet</key>
<array>
<string>Camaro</string>
<string>Corvette</string>
</array>
<key>Ford</key>
<array>
<string>Mustang</string>
<string>Kuga</string>
<string>Ranger</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

THE IDEA:
READ IN TABLE VIEW ONLY THE ARRAY SELECTED (IN EXAMPLE, CHEVROLET)

BUT WITH A SIMPLE SENTENCE (brand = [dict objectForKey:@"Chevrolet"];) WITHOUT LOOPS. PRESERVING IN THE NEW NSDICTIONARY **brand** THE ARRAY WITH THE KEY VALUE.

CURRENTLY I LOST THE KEY AND ONLY I CAN COPY THE ARRAY.

Comment: Why not persist the whole contents of the root plist?

Comment: how have you tried to copy the values from the old a `NSDictionary` into the new one? where is code for it? what is the contents of the `Cars.plist`?

Comment: I have edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `brand` object is a `NSArray`, not a `NSDictionary`, even though you declared it as an `NSDictionary`, so there is no "key". The `dic` dictionary seems however to be what you want: an association of a brand key with an array of models. As other have said, it's difficult to know exactly what you get without seeing the plist file.